# Example of generate('...') use in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to learn how to use puppet, following along with their [Quick Start Guide](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.6/reference/quick_start_helloworld.html).

I would like to add a time stamp using generate:

```
$timestamp = generate('/bin/date')

class helloworld::motd {
    file { '/etc/motd':
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    mode => '0644',
    content => "Production puppetmaster is in control. Last run: ${timestamp}\n",
    }
}
```

But the resulting motd file has no date/time:

`Production puppetmaster is in control. Last run:`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving the $timestamp assignment into the class block.

Comment: Still blank output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use generate() at all, that is something to be avoided at all costs.

Instead, take a look at the [stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) Puppet module, and the following functions in particular:

```
strftime()
time()
```

Example:
The following function call would result in a timestamp in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format:

```
$timestamp = stftime("%Y-%m-%d %k:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using [the built-in function generate() from the puppet language](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/function.html#generate) you can use it this way:

`$timestamp = generate('/bin/date', '+%Y%d%m %H:%M:%S')`

A more elaborate example is:

`$myuptime = generate("/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/uptime | /usr/bin/awk '{ print \$3}' | cut -d, -f 1 ")`

Please note the use of the quotes and the escaped $-sign.
I'm using the name $myuptime for my variable because $uptime is also available as a builtin.
Tested on puppet version 6.4.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.